# How to auto start Jboss bpms project

Tags: jboss, redhat, jboss-eap-6, business-process-management

I have a project which is developed on redhat jboss bpms but I want it to autostart when the AS is up. Or should I package it and deploy as a standalone application without bpms?

Or in other works how can I deploy it and where can I deploy it?

Thanks in advance for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using BPMS with default database(H2) and it stores DB tables in memory, so when you restart server deploymentInfo table is lost on restart.To resolve this issue change the DB connection URL in standalone.xml file

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
  <connection-url>jdbc:h2:file:~/jbpm-db</connection-url>
  <driver>h2</driver>
  <security>
    <user-name>sa</user-name>
  </security>
</datasource>
```

This datasource configuration will create DB tables into filesystem in USER_HOME directory